# I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong in this PIVOT

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've searched the site and I think I am doing this correctly, but it is late and I must be brain dead at this point. What is wrong with this PIVOT SQL?

```
SELECT  AccountNum  
        , MONTH(MAX(DealBookDate)) AS Month  
        , YEAR(MAX(DealBookDate))  AS Year  
FROM  
(  
    SELECT AccountNum   
         , MONTH(MAX(DealBookDate)) AS mth   
         , YEAR(MAX(DealBookDate))  AS yr   
         , DealBookDate  
    FROM vehicle.sales  
    WHERE accountnum IN  
    ('R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6', 'R7', 'R8', 'R9', 'R10', 'R11',   
'R12', 'R13', 'R14', 'R15')  
    GROUP BY  AccountNum  
            , DealBookDate  
) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
  COUNT(DealBookDate)  
    FOR AccountNum  
    IN  
    (  
    R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8, R9, R10, R11, R12, R13, R14, R15
    )  
)  
AS PivotTable;
```

Here is the error message I'm getting:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 31   Invalid column name
>   'AccountNum'.   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 32   Invalid column
>   name 'DealBookDate'.   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 33   Invalid
>   column name 'DealBookDate'.

Please be kind to me, it is a Monday after all.

Comment: In error message show your column is invalid. could you provide data?

Comment: Try using aliases for the tables and specify in the column names: AS PivotTable pt... and in the first select: MAX(pt.DealBookDate)...

Comment: @JuanCarlosEduardoRomainaAc The pt alias does not work.

Comment: @dwir182 I'm sorry, I will get in trouble if I provide any more data than I have already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct syntax.

```
CREATE SCHEMA vehicle
GO

CREATE TABLE vehicle.sales
(AccountNum VARCHAR(5) NULL,
DealBookDate DATETIME NULL)

INSERT INTO vehicle.sales (AccountNum, DealBookDate) VALUES('R1', '2018-09-18')
INSERT INTO vehicle.sales (AccountNum, DealBookDate) VALUES('R2', '2018-09-18')
INSERT INTO vehicle.sales (AccountNum, DealBookDate) VALUES('R3', '2018-09-18')
INSERT INTO vehicle.sales (AccountNum, DealBookDate) VALUES('R4', '2018-09-18')
INSERT INTO vehicle.sales (AccountNum, DealBookDate) VALUES('R5', '2018-09-18')
INSERT INTO vehicle.sales (AccountNum, DealBookDate) VALUES('R6', '2018-09-18')
INSERT INTO vehicle.sales (AccountNum, DealBookDate) VALUES('R7', '2018-09-18')
INSERT INTO vehicle.sales (AccountNum, DealBookDate) VALUES('R8', '2018-09-18')
INSERT INTO vehicle.sales (AccountNum, DealBookDate) VALUES('R9', '2018-09-18')
INSERT INTO vehicle.sales (AccountNum, DealBookDate) VALUES('R10', '2018-09-18')
INSERT INTO vehicle.sales (AccountNum, DealBookDate) VALUES('R11', '2018-09-18')
INSERT INTO vehicle.sales (AccountNum, DealBookDate) VALUES('R12', '2018-09-18')
INSERT INTO vehicle.sales (AccountNum, DealBookDate) VALUES('R13', '2018-09-18')
INSERT INTO vehicle.sales (AccountNum, DealBookDate) VALUES('R14', '2018-09-18')
INSERT INTO vehicle.sales (AccountNum, DealBookDate) VALUES('R15', '2018-09-18')

SELECT AccountNum   
        , MONTH(MAX(DealBookDate)) AS mth   
        , YEAR(MAX(DealBookDate))  AS yr   
        , DealBookDate  
FROM vehicle.sales  
WHERE accountnum IN  
('R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6', 'R7', 'R8', 'R9', 'R10', 'R11','R12', 'R13', 'R14', 'R15')  
GROUP BY  AccountNum, DealBookDate  

SELECT  R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8, R9, R10, R11, R12, R13, R14, R15,
    mth, yr
FROM  
(  
    SELECT AccountNum   
         , MONTH(MAX(DealBookDate)) AS mth   
         , YEAR(MAX(DealBookDate))  AS yr   
         , DealBookDate  
    FROM vehicle.sales  
    WHERE accountnum IN  
    ('R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6', 'R7', 'R8', 'R9', 'R10', 'R11','R12', 'R13', 'R14', 'R15')  
    GROUP BY  AccountNum, DealBookDate  
) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
  COUNT(DealBookDate)  
    FOR AccountNum  
    IN  (R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8, R9, R10, R11, R12, R13, R14, R15)  
)  
AS PivotTable;  

DROP TABLE vehicle.sales
GO
DROP SCHEMA vehicle
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

try below way

```
   SELECT   *  
        FROM  
        (  
            SELECT * 
            FROM vehicle.sales  
            WHERE accountnum IN  
            ('R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6', 'R7', 'R8', 'R9', 'R10', 'R11',   
        'R12', 'R13', 'R14', 'R15')             
        ) AS SourceTable  
        PIVOT  
        (  
          COUNT(DealBookDate)  
            FOR AccountNum  
            IN  
            (  
            [R1], [R2], [R3], [R4], [R5], [R6],[R7],[R8],[R9], [R10], [R11], [R12], [R13], [R14], [R15]
            )  
        )  
        AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: I can't use a SELECT *. the DBAs have that blocked for use.